# У меня локальный openserver, я скачал файлзилу и хочу подключиться к моему локальному хостингу. Где мне найти Хост и порт. Что туда вводить?

Tags: openserver

Я знаю, что файлзила не нужна для локалхоста как денвер или опенсервер. Но я хочу просто научиться пользоваться файлзилой пока через локалхост и загружать туда файлы

Хост ввожу 127.0.0.1, порт пустой, да и с портом 21 и др не работает

Все равно ошибка

> Статус: Соединяюсь с 127.0.0.1:21...
>   Статус: Не удалось установить соединение с "ECONNREFUSED - Соединение отклонено сервером".
>   Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу

Можно ли вообще подключиться через filezilla или totalcomander к локальному серверу openserver или denwer?

Comment: В настройках опен сервера надо во вкладке `ftp server` во-первых, если нет то добавить юзера и папку, котрую он будет открывать... во-вторых надо поставить галочку `запускать FTP сервер`

Comment: а если для denver ?

Comment: Не знаю)) я этой фигней давно не пользуюсь... слишком он устарел и никчемная сборка стала......говорят у денвера нет ФТП

Comment: спасибо - сделайте ответом -

Answer (score -1):

Хост: localhost или 127.0.0.1
Имя пользователя: ftp
Пароль: ftp
Порт: 21

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?